# random javascript AI function for tic tac toe not working

Tags: javascript

Working on a Tic Tac Toe game with straight JS with a player vs cpu set-up. I have tried to figure out a random function for the cpu turn. It is hitting the function and going through it. The console.log(cpuTurn()); always returns false after the player marks a square.

I have played around with this line which I believe is the issue: if (i == "")blanks.push([i]);

If I declare a var such as Val and put it in front of like like so: if (Val(i) == "")... I will get an error stating 'Val' is not a function.

I'm totally confused as to what I need to do here...

```js
var player = "X";
var cpu = "O";
var currentTurn = player;

function startGame() {

 for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  clearBoard(i);
 }

 document.winner = null;
 setMessage("Player " + currentTurn + ", please start the game.");
}

function setMessage(message) {
 document.getElementById("message").innerText = message;
} 

function nextMove(square) {
 if (document.winner != null) {
  setMessage(currentTurn + " has already won.");
 } else if(square.innerText == '') {
   square.innerText = currentTurn;
   swapTurn();  
 } else {
  setMessage("No cheating, choose another square.");
 }
}

function swapTurn() {
 if(checkForWinner(currentTurn)) {
  setMessage(currentTurn + " has won!");
  document.winner = currentTurn; 
 } else if(checkForDraw(currentTurn)) {
  setMessage("Its a draw!");
 } else if(currentTurn == player){
  currentTurn = cpu;
  setMessage("Player " + currentTurn + ", it's your turn.");
  cpuMove();
 } else {
  currentTurn = player;
  setMessage("Player " + currentTurn + ", it's your turn.");
 }
}

function checkForWinner(move) {
 var result = false;
 if(checkRow(1,2,3, move) ||
    checkRow(4,5,6, move) ||
    checkRow(7,8,9, move) ||
    checkRow(1,4,7, move) ||
    checkRow(2,5,8, move) ||
    checkRow(3,6,9, move) ||
    checkRow(1,5,9, move) ||
    checkRow(3,5,7, move)) {
     result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

function checkForDraw(move) {
 var draw = false;
 if (((getBox(1) == "X") || (getBox(1) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(2) == "X") || (getBox(2) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(3) == "X") || (getBox(3) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(4) == "X") || (getBox(4) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(5) == "X") || (getBox(5) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(6) == "X") || (getBox(6) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(7) == "X") || (getBox(7) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(8) == "X") || (getBox(8) == "O")) && 
  ((getBox(9) == "X") || (getBox(9) == "O"))) {
         draw = true;
        }
         return draw;  
}

function checkRow(a, b, c, move) {
 var result = false;
 if(getBox(a) == move && getBox(b) == move && getBox(c) == move) {
  result = true;
 }
 return result;
}

function getBox(number) {         
 return document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText; 
}

function clearBoard(number) {
 document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText = "";
}

function cpuMove() {
 var blanks = [];
 //var val = 0;
 for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  if (i == "")blanks.push([i]);
 }
 if (blanks.length > 0) {
   var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*blanks.length));
        return blanks[r];
      } else {
        return false;
      } 
}
```

```css
 <style>

  body {
   width:550px;
   margin: auto;
  }

  h1 {

  }

  #message {
   font-family:; 
   font-size:;
  }

  .square {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 60pt;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
  }

 </style>
```

```html
<body onload="startGame();">
 <h1>Tom's Tic Tac Toe in JS</h1>

 <div id="message">MESSAGE HERE</div>

 <table border = "1">
  <tr>
   <td class="square" id="s1" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
   <td class="square" id="s2" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
   <td class="square" id="s3" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="square" id="s4" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
   <td class="square" id="s5" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
   <td class="square" id="s6" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="square" id="s7" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
   <td class="square" id="s8" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
   <td class="square" id="s9" onClick="nextMove(this)"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <a href="javascript: startGame();" id="restart">New Game</a>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read through a ton of questions here in Stack but nothing seems to be similar to my issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the debugger, it should be pretty easy to step through the code and see what's happening.

Comment: var Val = 0; and you are using it like Val(i)??

Comment: how is `i == ""` integer comparing to string?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but when would `i` ever be "" if you're assigning `i` in your for loop?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is where I am stuck in finding a way of iterating through the squares to determine if there is either an X or O in it. My noobness to JS is killing me. I thought about and couldn't get to work was to use my getBox function to find the # of blanks. But pushing my limits of JS I couldn't get anything to work. So wrote the above on paper and it seemed to make sense except this one line... putting a value to i to find the blank squares. I am open to any suggestions. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you.
Let me know if you have trouble understanding I will explain

```
function cpuMove() {

  var blanks = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    var place = document.getElementById("s"+i).innerText
    if(place == "") blanks.push([i]);
  }
  if (blanks.length > 0) {
    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * blanks.length));
    nextMove(document.getElementById("s"+blanks[r]));
  } 
}
```